# Prisma Implicit M2N relationship doesn't apply pagination on nested object

Tags: pagination, relationship, prisma

have a model with stores and articles.
stores have many articles and articles many stores

As this is an implicit M2N, Prisma has generated automatically the Join table `_articlesTohypermarches_stores`

The max number of articles per store is 10K, but I want for example only the 10 first and not the whole 10K
I tried to apply pagination when querying the stores but the query sent to the `_articlesTohypermarches_stores` table has `no LIMIT 10` thus resulting in fetching the 10K articles...

here are the query I'm testing, the model and the the queries sent to POSTGRES by Prisma, as well as the PRISMA Logs that showing the pb.

```
const test = await prisma.hypermarches_stores.findMany({
    where: {
      id: {
        equals: 209,
      },
    },
    select: {
      stoDisplayDesc: true,
      articles: {
        take: 10, // <--- this is not taking into account
        skip: 1,
        select: {
          title: true,
        },
      },
    },
    take: 2,
  });



model articles {
  id                            Int                          @id(map: "PK_0a6e2c450d83e0b6052c2793334")  @default(autoincrement()) 
  title                         String?                         @default("") @db.VarChar(3000)
  prioriteId                    Int?                        
  isAlerte                      Boolean?                        @default(false)
  categorieId                   Int?                         
  publicationStartDate          DateTime?                       @default(dbgenerated("'2021-12-29 17:02:14.651'::timestamp without time zone")) @db.Timestamp(6)
  publicationEndDate            DateTime?                       @default(dbgenerated("'2021-12-29 17:02:14.651'::timestamp without time zone")) @db.Timestamp(6)
  hasAction                     Boolean?                        @default(false)
  briefDescription              String?                         @default("") @db.VarChar(3000)
  content                       String?                         @default("")
  contact1                      String?                         @default("") @db.VarChar(300)
  contact2                      String?                         @default("") @db.VarChar(300)
  author                        String?                         @default("") @db.VarChar(300)
  recordCreationDate            DateTime                        @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(6)
  recordUpdateDate              DateTime                        @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(6)
  ref_categories                ref_categories?                 @relation(fields: [categorieId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "FK_278d87b271a80d56e5d6cc0f888")
  ref_priorites                 ref_priorites?                  @relation(fields: [prioriteId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "FK_a55acd217d26e0d60f57b5f38f7")
  articles_documents            articles_documents[]
  fonctions                     ref_fonctions[]
  magasins                      hypermarches_stores[]
  metiers              ref_metiers[]
  perimetres           ref_perimetres[]
  poles                ref_poles[]
  services             ref_services[]
  articles_statuts_contribution articles_statuts_contribution[]

  @@index([id], map: "IDX_0a6e2c450d83e0b6052c279333")
}


model hypermarches_stores {
  id                             Int                   @id(map: "PK_7b1178bff8dc98cbd6d68fc2dd0") @default(autoincrement()) 
  stoEan                         String                   @unique(map: "UQ_7fddfa16362979011e27b4d0b21") @db.VarChar(300)
  articles              articles[]
  @@index([id], map: "IDX_7b1178bff8dc98cbd6d68fc2dd")
}
```

[image]

Comment: To clarify, the issue you're pointing out is with the underlying SQL not being perfectly efficient and _not_ that the result returned by Prisma is incorrect, is this right? I replicated your query and the _result_ returned by the Prisma Client has only 10 results and not every related `article` record.

Comment: exactly. The problem is that the queries sent to the DB are not optimized although Prisma gives us the tools and parameters to manage databases with several millions of lines. Unfortunately, these tools and parameters are not "reflected" in the SQL Queries, thus destoying their benefit. Unless I do it the wrong way (I'm new in Prisma, more a typeORM guy).

Comment: Alright, this looks like a bug/issue. It happens for `findUnique` too.  Would you please consider creating an [issue on Github](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new/choose) about this, specifying exactly what the problem is with the generated SQL? We'll have someone on the engineering team track it and fix it as soon as we can.

Comment: have opened a question yesterday on this here. I might change or duplicated it to an issue ? https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/10932

Comment: Yep, I would suggest creating an issue instead. It would be super helpful if you structured it using the bug report template provided.

Comment: done here : https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/10949

Comment: Thanks a lot! We will follow up on this on the issue moving forward.

Comment: you're welcome. It's an important topic for big relatinnal DBs